# javascript - get value of a text box that contains a date?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a text box with a date (gotten with a date picker) and now I am trying to get the value of my text box using JavaScript. For some reason my function is returning null or it just errs.Can anyone help me?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" name="txtStartDate" runat="server" MaxLength="100"   CausesValidation="True"
                                                                     ValidationGroup="PriorAuth" CssClass="effect"></asp:TextBox>

<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="ceStartDate" runat="server" Format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                                                                    PopupButtonID="ImageButton1" TargetControlID="txtStartDate" PopupPosition="BottomRight" />

 alert("date: " + Date.parse(document.getElementsByName('txtStartDate').value));
                var startDate = Date.parse(document.getElementsByName('txtStartDate').value);
```

Answer (score 1):

one thing is: `getElementsByName` should return an array of elements

Point to whichever index makes sense:

`document.getElementsByName('txtStartDate')[0].value`

or you could use `getElementById`

Comment: they are both undefined

Answer (score 1):

Is
`document.getElementById("<%=txtStartDate.ClientID %>").value;`
what  you wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET renders elements ID's differently, you can grab the ID like so:

```
Date.parse(document.getElementById('<%= txtStartDate.ClientID %>').value)
```